# Index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 in size 1 in Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, a-star, maze

For a university assignment I was asked to convert a 1 line text file into a 2d array. However, when I run the program, I get this error:

```
(venv) D:\Uni Stuff\Year 2\AIGP\Assignment\PYTHONASSIGNMEN>python astar.py
Input file name: Lab9TerrainFile1.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Uni Stuff\Year 2\AIGP\Assignment\PYTHONASSIGNMEN\astar.py", line 129, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Uni Stuff\Year 2\AIGP\Assignment\PYTHONASSIGNMEN\astar.py", line 110, in main
    number_of_rows = maze_file[1]
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

This is the code for generating the maze:

```
def main():

    maze_file = open(input("Input file name: "), "r").readlines()

    maze_file = np.array([maze_file])

    number_of_columns = maze_file[0]

    number_of_rows = maze_file[1]

    maze_column = np.array_split(maze_file[2:8], number_of_columns)

    maze_row = np.array_split(maze_file[2:8], number_of_rows)

    maze = np.concatenate([maze_column][maze_row])

    start = np.where(maze == 2)

    end = np.where(maze == 3)

    maze_file.close()

    path = astar(maze, start, end)
    print(path)
```

Any help would be appreciated and thank you!

Comment: You are trying to access the second index (i.e. `1`) of an array which has only one item.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but `readlines()` returns a list, so `[maze_file]` is a list-of-lists.  Is that intentional?

Comment: let me edit the ```readlines()```

Answer (score 1):

You can test this by checking the size of your array *maze_file* by running the code below.

```
print(len(maze_file))
```

If it returns 1, then it means it only has 1 element.

maze_file[0] means you are getting the first element. Hence, the index 0 between the square brackets. When you specify maze_file[1], its trying to get the 2nd element, which doesn't exists. Hence the error Index out of Bounds.

Reviewing your code, it looks like you are trying to get the number of columns and rows for the array. You can use the following code.

```
number_of_columns = len(maze_file)
number_of_rows = len(maze_file[0])
```